# Unable to run sql on my IBM Db2 workspace

Tags: sql, db2

Error message

```
[jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
```

I have tried everything suggested by the IBM chatbot but I did not get a solution. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This means it failed due to disabled or expired user id or wrong password or not a valid password.
Please contact your DB administrator